# How can you conditionally tell TypeScript which data type to use?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I have a situation where a value can return either a string or an object.

The interface is defined as so:

```
interface RoutesType {
  projects: string | {
    all: string;
    favorite: string;
    critical: string;
  };
```

And the value is from here:

```
const routes = {
  projects: include('/projects/', {
    all: '',
    favorite: 'favorite/',
    critical: 'critical/'
  }
};
```

When I try to access `routes.projects.critical`, it displays the following error:

```
Property 'critical' does not exist on type 'string | { all: string; favorite: string; critical: string;}'. 
  Property 'critical' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

Is there any reasonable way to conditionally tell TS I'm trying to access the object `routes.projects` and not the string?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WolQLw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared/unimported types or values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the type of the property `projects` before accessing it:

```js
if (typeof routes.projects !== 'string') {
    // you can now access routes.projects.critical
}
```